# React desktop application - error when trying to interact with server

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, desktop-application, webview2

I have Desktop app with React, Typescript, ASP.NET Core and WebView2 which I used this article to create:

https://www.codementor.io/@gabrieleferreri/write-a-desktop-app-with-react-typescript-asp-net-core-and-webview2-1irclqmu8f

When I run the application in "dotnet run" mode, my application opens up in chrome on localhost:5000 and I can interact with my API controller.
But when I build the application for release and execute the EXE file, I can no longer interact between the react app and my API controller.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

.............

Comment: In your app can you try changing your WebView2 to navigate to https://example.com instead of https://localhost so you can see if the issue is WebView2 not initializing versus, WebView2 is unable to interact with your localhost server? If the issue is WebView2 cannot initialize, make sure you have WebView2 Runtime installed. Also make sure that your app executable is running in a folder with write permission or specify a different folder for the WebView2 user data folder.